# swift build use of unresolved identifier

Tags: vapor, swift-package-manager

I used [vapor](https://github.com/vapor/vapor) to build a project. create a swift file using xcode.

structure like this:

```
├── Sources
│   └──App
│   │   └── Controllers
│   │   └── Models
│   │   │   └── File.swift
│   └──Run
│       └── main.swift
└── Package.swift
```

with main.swift

```
let config = try Config()
try config.setup()
let drop = try Droplet(config)
try drop.setup()
File.test()
try drop.run()
```

with File.swift

```
class File {

    class func test() -> Void{
        print("--\(self)--");
    }
}
```

the above code xcode can run normally. but using the command `swift build` to get an error.

log:

```
Compile Swift Module 'App' (6 sources)
Compile Swift Module 'Run' (1 sources)
/Users/xxx/Documents/testServer/Sources/Run/main.swift:25:1: error: use of 
unresolved identifier 'File'
File.test()
^~~~
CoreServices.cFile:1:12: note: did you mean 'cFile'?
public var cFile: OSType { get }
           ^
<unknown>:0: error: build had 1 command failures
error: exit(1):  /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/swift-build-tool -f /Users/xxx/Documents/testServer/.build/debug.yamlhere
```

Answer (score 3):

Your `main.swift` is in module `Run`, while `File` is in module `App`. To call a method of a class from another module, you have to perform the following:

1. Make the class (`File`) `public`
2. Make the method (`test`) `public`
3. Import the module in the file of the calling method - add `import App` to `main.swift`

Comment: thanks . It start working.but how do I add the class File to `Run` sources inside it?

Comment: To use class `File` inside the source files of module `Run` - just add `import App` to every source file you will use class `File`.

Comment: how to do it. can you give me an example? link?

Comment: In your case: `import App` and then `File.test()` in the files you want to call `File.test()`.

Comment: Maybe I misunderstand your question - could you please restate it? Are you asking how to call methods of `File` class from source files of `Run` module?

Comment: I mean to add the `File` class to the `Run` module.  what should I do

Comment: To add the `File` class to the `Run` module, just move it, on disk, from the `App` folder to the `Run` folder.

Answer (score 1):

Probably what is happening is that your class `File` is in the target 'App', while your `Main` is in target 'Run', so one can't see the other.

What you need to do is to add the line `File.test()` into `Droplet+setup.swift` file over `setup()` function, that you might have in your project located over the 'App' target.

Some thing like this:

```
@_exported import Vapor

extension Droplet {
    public func setup() throws {
        try setupRoutes()
        // ADD YOUR CLASS CALL OVER HERE
        File.test()

    }

}
```

Comment: but how do I add the class File to `Run` sources inside it?